# Drag and Drop local file with autoIt and selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

i am trying to drag and drop a file from local machine to container area in my web application. 
Html of the drop area

```
 <div class="abcde">
            <label>Select file(s) and drag here to upload</label>
        </div>
```

My code

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='abcde']")).click();
AutoIt.AutoItX.WinActive("Open");
AutoItX.Send(@"C:\Users\1234\Desktop\upp.txt");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Drag and Drop doesn't work with this code

Comment: [_ClipPutFile](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_ClipPutFile.htm)